# Функция, записывающая целые числа в формате ...,00

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли функция, записывающая целые числа в формате ...,00, и при этом в числовом формате, а не строковом? (т.е. чтобы у каждого числа, целого или дробного, были обязательно 2 цифры после запятой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FormatFloat](http://www.delphibasics.ru/FormatFloat.php)

В вашем случае строка формата будет `'#,00'`.

Comment: Спасибо, Nofate!